# Book on functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I recently started functional analysis in more depth. I followed a standard course on functional analysis at the master's degree but clearly it was very basic and many results are deeper than the one it covered.

I'm looking for a book which starts from topological vector spaces and goes through to metric spaces, normed spaces, Banach spaces and Hilbert spaces. IN this sense [Rudin, Functional analysis] is surely the right book. Are there some simpler alternatives to Rudin's book with this structure so that I can read 2 or more books?

(Also [Yosida, Functional analysis] has this kind of structure but it is too advanced and very difficult to read for me).

Comment: A book that starts out general (topological groups, then topological vector spaces) and only later gets to more specialized settings (normed/Banach spaces, then inner-product/Hilbert spaces) is [**Lectures in Functional Analysis and Operator Theory**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387900802) by Sterling Khazag Berberian (1974). Although I've had my copy since the late 1970s, I've never dealt with it much (only occasionally over the years looking up something in it), so I don't know how suitable it would be for your purposes.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts what is the one which has most intuitive proofs and that explains them as much as possible?

Comment: Thanks to all for the answer by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486453529) is a classic that starts with topological vector spaces and works down. It's a Dover publication.

I think this is what you're looking for.